# bash: Extract 2 information out of three lines

Tags: bash

I have trouble with parsing a logfile... Here is a logfile sample (in real live there are bash color codes included):

```
foo completely unintresting line bar
foo [INFO] [#############] bar 
foo [INFO] [#######______] bar
```

I need the parts "[#############]" and "[#######**__**]". To get these information I drop the unintresting lines with:

```
CMD_TAIL=`tail -n 3 server.log | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}((;[0-9]{1,3})*)?)?[m|K]//g" | grep -E '\[INFO\] \[[#_]+\]'`
```

But if I "walk" the CMD_TAIL I get this (whitespace replaced by newline):

```
1: foo :2
1: [INFO] :2
1: [#############] :2
1: bar :2
...
```

How do I get the complete line so I can extract the needed information?

Comment: What is your input file content? Your currrent script to parse it? what is the expected output and what is the current output? Please specify these properly. From your question these 4 things are not clear!

Comment: Always provide these information. You'll get correct answer quickly.

Comment: I had, but not very structured because I was in wtf mode ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're in a bash-like shell, try setting the internal field separator to newline before your loop:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for TAIL in $CMD_TAIL; do
    echo "1: $TAIL :2"
done
```

Comment: This was the problem -.- Thank you!